# Google Analytics event values not recorded from angular 8 project

Tags: google-analytics, angular8, google-analytics-4

I'm using Google Analytics to track user activities. However, the value of the events are recorded as zero even I'm firing events from service.

The followed the steps from the following link: [How To Properly Add Google Analytics Tracking to Your Angular Web App](https://medium.com/madhash/how-to-properly-add-google-analytics-tracking-to-your-angular-web-app-bc7750713c9e)

[image: image of event from Google Analytics]

My Code:

```
googleanalytics.service.ts

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
declare let gtag:Function;


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoogleanalyticsService {

  constructor() { }

  public eventEmitter( 
    Eventname: string, 
    Eventcategory: string, 
    Eventaction: string, 
    Eventlabel: string = null,  
    Eventvalue: number = null ){ 
         gtag('event', Eventname, { 
                 Eventcategory: Eventcategory, 
                 Eventlabel: Eventlabel, 
                 Eventaction: Eventaction, 
                 Eventvalue: Eventvalue
               })
    }
public event2(
  
    Eventcategory: string, 
    Eventaction: string, 
    Eventlabel: string = null,  
    Eventvalue: number 
){
  gtag('send', {
    hitType: 'event',
    eventCategory: Eventcategory,
    eventAction: Eventaction,
    eventLabel: Eventlabel,
    Eventvalue: Eventvalue
  });
}
    public setGAUser(userid){
      gtag('set',{'user_id': userid}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.})

    }
}
```

samplecomponent.ts:

```
this.GAService.eventEmitter('user_completed_form','user','click','user',30);
```

Please, suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events in `gtag` have this syntax:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

The second parameter you called *Eventname* actually is the `action`. Try following the above construct and you will see that it will work correctly.

Comment: hi, thank u for the answer it worked like a charm. But I would like to know, can we string as an event value? Also, can we generate a unique user-id in google analytics(string by me)?

Comment: No, event value can only be a positive integer, otherwise it is 0. It is a metric, so it is can't be a string.

Comment: what about the user id? ex: `gtag('set',{'user_id': userid});` .  Even though I'm sending the user id as a variable that I want, but in google analytics, it is showing the auto-generated one.

Comment: Open another answer pls, so we can add some code if necessary and because the question is a different topic, thx